# .htaccess rewrite issue

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, shared-hosting, rewrite

Below is my .htaccess file for my website on shared hosting - I'm attempting to send all requests to index.php with parameter 'q' where I wish to parse data etc... unless it's an existing file or directory.

So my issue, if I attempt to browse to an actual directory expecting to get an unauthorized notice (options -Indexes) it sends me to my index.php and I also noticed that `print_r($_GET)` it gives me this: `Array ( [q] => 403.shtml )`

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Help would be much appreciated if possible :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP incorrectly answered her own question:

> This ended up being an issue with mod_security on my shared hosting environment. My hosting provider whitelisted the domain against the rules being triggered by mod_security, problem solved.